# characters display of a text file in java

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains a line as a,b,a,b,a,b and I want to display the line as b,b,b,a,a,a

any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: *"any assistance would be appreciated"* As will any sign of effort on your part, and a specific question.

Comment: @Andrew The problem here is no matter whether you have tried anything or not, there are people here who are ready to answer anything.

Comment: @vikiiii  Too many dancing Poodles, not enough Rottweilers. ;)

Comment: Looking at your previous questions you seem to answer and accept them all yourself!

Comment: not really...may be couple of them...as they might help someone else...but i have accepted others answers promptly

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code handout question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main( String[] args) {
        String line="a,b,a,b,a,b";
        String[] split = line.split( "," );
        Arrays.sort( split );
        for ( int i = split.length -1; i > 0 ; i--) {
            System.out.print( split[i] );
            System.out.print( "," );
        }
        System.out.print( split[0] );
    }
```

Comment: if (i == 2){
           System.out.println("3rd line");
           System.out.println(aryLines[i]);
           //String line="a,b,a,b,a,b";
                 String[] split = aryLines[i].split( "," );
                 //aryLines[i].sort( split );
                 for ( int j = split.length -1; j > 0 ; j--) {
                     System.out.print( split[j] );
                     System.out.print( "," );
                 }
                 System.out.print( split[0] );
            
           
                      
          }

Comment: Arrays.sort is not compiling for me?

Answer (score 1):

- Use `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method to read a line from the file.
- Use `String`'s `split()` to split the line into tokens (characters in this case).
- Sort the array returned from `String.split()` using `Arrays.sort()` (note that the order will be the opposite to that required so you should reverse through the array when printing), or store the array into an `ArrayList` and use `Collections.sort()` and specify your own `Comparator`.

Answer (score 0):

Split the text based on ','

Just create an array and keep storing elements on that array , sort this array whatever way you want to , and the print the output

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it into steps:

1. Open the file
2. Read the line from the file
3. Parse the line into individual elements
4. Add the elements to a data structure
5. Sort the data structure
6. Reverse the order
7. Display the data structure, either by rendering the contents or creating a String

Which part are you having trouble with?